# Django request.POST returns an empty dict

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

code skips the whole if block directly goes to the last else. I am using django.forms to get input from the user. the same thing happens when the method is set to GET. I tried the same with normal HTML forms the same result. But the weird fact it earlier It was working properly in the initial stages of the project while I was experimenting with my views and models this start causing the error in my project as I cannot get the user input.

views.py

```
def form(request):
    form = InputForm()
    return render(request, 'classifier/form.html', {'form':form})

def output(request):
    print(request.POST) #  returns empty dict
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = form.cleaned_data['input_url']
            print(url)
            return render(request, 'classifier/output.html', {'url':url})
        else:
            print(form.errors())

    else:
        print("error")
        error = "Oops"

    return render(request, 'classifier/output.html',{'url':error})
```

form.html

```
<form action="{% url 'classifier:output' %}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {% for non_field_error in form.non_field_error %}
      <p class="help is-danger">{{ non_field_error}}</p>
   {% endfor %}
   {{ form }}
   {% for error in form.erros %}
       <p class="help is-danger">{{ error }}</p>
   {% endfor %}
   <div class="text-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" value='Save'><a href="{% url 'classifier:output' %}">Submit</a></button>
   </div>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'classifier'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('form/',views.form, name='form'),
    path('output/',views.output, name='output'),
]
```

Comment: <form method="post"> ?

Comment: yes , set it to POST. I even tried by changing it to GET then using request.GET. but same results

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: are you sure `<form action="">` is on this page?

Comment: I have edited the question @gunsodo

Comment: I have provided my HTML. hope this helps. @crazyzubr

Comment: it would be useful to attach *urls.py*

Comment: The problem is your submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template:

```
<div class="text-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" value='Save'><a href="{% url 'classifier:output' %}">Submit</a></button>
   </div>
```

Submit button in reality is link: `<a href="{% url 'classifier:output' %}">Submit</a>`

so there is a simple link following.

The corrected part of the code looks like this:

```
<div class="text-center">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Submit</button>
       </div>
```

Comment: I have added urls.py to my question. When I changed the code as per your suggestions the button doesn't work then. How can I route to my output template and take user input at the same time by the click of a button? @crazyzubr

Comment: @SANKETMHATRE the button should now work. you are missing something. try copying the code from my example and pasting the template.